# How to iterate through items in ObjectBox

Tags: flutter, objectbox

Using ObjectBox, I need to iterate through every item in a large box, making changes one at a time. There are over a million entries in the box, so I can't read it into memory first, I really need to work one item at a time.

The ID's are not sequential, as many items have been removed. So I can't simply iterate by get(id). Is there some way to read the items direct from the box using an index value, as with a List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to query for all IDs:

```
final ids = box.query().build().findIds();
```

Then get each object by ID (can be null if it was removed in the meanwhile):

```
for (var id in ids) {
    final exampleObject = box.get(id);
    // TODO Change the object.
    box.put(exampleObject);
    // For better performance, might want to collect
    // a batch of changed objects and save them together
    // using box.putMany
}
```

If it's also fine to work on a group of objects, and assuming the data does not change in the meantime, you might be able to use a `Query` with limit and offset instead:

```
final query = box.query().build();
// In a loop:
query
  ..offset = 0 // Start at 0, then o = o + n * limit
  ..limit = 100; // Choose depending on how large your objects are
final results = query.find();
// Stop once there are no (or less than limit) results.
```

Comment: Thanks Uwe! .offset and .limit are what I needed :)